# Excel Tab with Record Macro

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I cannot find Record Macro in Excel 2010.  I thought I remember it being in a hidden taskbar tab.  I cannot find the setting in Excel Options.  Maybe it's a registry hack.

Where is the setting to enable the hidden macro settings?

Answer (score 1):

I found it!  It's in Excel Options, Customize Ribbon, check Developer (on the right side).